# C# Changing the Size of a button text

Tags: c#, winforms, button, resize

I want that the Size of the Button font changes dynamically, when I change the size of the Button.
So far I have placed the button on the right Location and the Size of the Button changes, when I resize the Form. But When the Button becomes to small for the text in the Button the letters just 'fall' out.

How can I change the Size of the Buttons text depending on the Button size itself?

Comment: It is WinForms sorry for that...

Answer (score 6):

**To make the text in the button responsive use the following code:**

```
    //paint event from button:
    private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        float fontSize = NewFontSize(e.Graphics, button1.Size, button1.Font, button1.Text);

        // set font with Font Class and the returned Size from NewFontSize();
        Font f = new Font("Arial", fontSize, FontStyle.Bold);
        button1.Font = f;
    }

    // method to calculate the size for the font:
    public static float NewFontSize(Graphics graphics, Size size, Font font, string str)
    {
        SizeF stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(str, font);
        float wRatio = size.Width / stringSize.Width;
        float hRatio = size.Height / stringSize.Height;
        float ratio = Math.Min(hRatio, wRatio);
        return font.Size * ratio;
    }
```

**Example of code in action:**

[image: Example of code in action]

> As you see font will be resizeable inside the button. And the text
>   will not be thrown out of the button. You also can use this for other 
>   Controllers as well.

Comment: And how do I change it dynamically with the size of the button?

Comment: I've changed my post and I figured out how to accomplish this. @Stujo

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide details in regards to font, size, and what not, I will do a general snippet just to point you in the right direction. Please modify its parameters according to your needs.

```
Button button = (Button)sender;
button.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
```

Or even something simpler

```
button.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10);
```

Comment: And how do I change it dynamically with the size of the button?

Comment: `button.Font = new Font(button.Font.FontFamily, button.Font.Size*1.1f);`? With or without *1.1f part?...

Answer (score 0):

You want to check how much height and width you have for the button first.

Then code a loop on 1pt font to something like 200

in each loop call `TextRenderer.MeasureText(button.text, button.font);` pass the same font but with the point size from the loop.

Then verify if the height and width from the `MeasureText` fits in the button limits you have given yourself. If it fits try the next higher size. If it doesn't fit, the best font size if the previous one.

Comment: And how do I change it dynamically with the size of the button?

Comment: bind to an event of the button to trigger this code like the `SizeChanged` event

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic changing, I would try something like this.
But it's only solve dynamic changing. For checking the text width, you need implement some more functionality to this code.

```
    public class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {

    }

    public override bool AutoSize {
        get {
            return false;
        }
        set {
            base.AutoSize = false;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);

        Font = new Font(this.Font.FontFamily,Height-10,this.Font.Style,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    }
}
```